# How to determine how many times api is being called using httptestingcontroller

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I am sure api is called multiple times,I want to determine how many times is the api getting called, I am using httptestingcontroller for this purpose.

const req = httpMock.expectOne('/api/getrecords'); fails

```
it('should return one object', () => {
      var dummyObject : any[];
     dummyObject = [
        {
          account: "shjdhjhs",
          produc: "xyz",
          feature: "ejfjf",

        }
      ];

      const req = httpMock.expectOne('/api/getrecords');
     //fails, as this api is called many times
      expect(req.request.method).toBe("GET");
      req.flush( dummyObject);

      expect(component.Financials.length).toBe(1);
      expect(component.Financials).toEqual( dummyObject);

    //test for how many times this api is getting called?

  });
```

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested this personally, but I think you can use `httpMock.match` which returns a list of matching requests. The length of that list should be equal to the number of times the endpoint was called.

Link to docs: https://angular.io/api/common/http/testing/HttpTestingController#match

Comment: const req = httpMock.match('/api/getrecords'); then printing req and req.length prints empty array and zero respectively

Comment: I don't see you actially invoking any methods in the pasted test - are you sure the code calling the API is properly invoked?

Comment: you are correct Thor , after invoking the method I can print the array . its not empty